# Recursive IEnumerable menu in .NET MVC4 returning no results

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, recursion, entity-framework-6

I am trying to return a nested list of pages within my application using a recursive helper. However I am getting no results back in my IEnumerable, so that nodes.Any() is empty.

The shared layout page and section of html that calls the navbar section
**_Layout**

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    @RenderSection("NavigationBar", false)
</div>
```

In the view there is a section that calls the action to render the navigation bar
**Index.cshtml**

```
@section NavigationBar{
    @{Html.Action("Menu", "Page");}
}
```

The **PageController** action "*Menu*" is as follows

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    var pagesQuery = new MyMVC.BLL.GetPagesQuery();
    var pages = pagesQuery.GetPages();
    return PartialView("_Navigation", pages);
}
```

The **pagesQuery** is simply:

```
public IEnumerable<PageContent> GetPages()
{
    _context = _context ?? new dbEntities();
    return _context.PageContents.Where(t => t.PageActive == true && t.ParentPageId != null)
            .OrderBy(t => t.PageOrder);
}
```

And the **_Navigation** partial view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMVC.DAL.PageContent>

@BuildMenu(Model)

@helper BuildMenu(IEnumerable<MyMVC.DAL.PageContent> data, int? parentid = null)
{
    var nodes = from n in data where n.ParentPageId == parentid select n;
    if (nodes.Any()) {
        foreach (var node in nodes.OrderBy(n => n.PageOrder)) {
            @node.PageTitle        
            @BuildMenu(data, node.PageId);
        }
    }
 }
```

When I run the following linq code within LinqPad (the same as the var nodes line above) I get the correct result and 7 top level items.

```
int? x = null;
var y = from n in PageContents where n.ParentPageId == x select n;
foreach (var title in y){
    Console.Write (title.PageTitle + "|");  
}
```

the same line (Bolded above) within the Partial doesn't return any results. I'm sure the answer is really simple, but I've been fighting this a couple of days now and it's bugging me.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The condition in your `GetPages` method has `t.ParentPageId != null`. Wouldn't that mean the first call `@BuildMenu(Model)` will find no nodes since parentId will be null?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. FFS. i'll give that a try tonight. it certainly looks like the issue. could you possibly stick that comment down as an answer so I can upvote/mark as the question answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in your `GetPages` method has `t.ParentPageId != null`:

```
return _context.PageContents
               .Where(t => t.PageActive == true && t.ParentPageId != null)
               .OrderBy(t => t.PageOrder);
```

Then your partial view will call the `BuildMenu` helper initially without a parentId, so its default value `null` will be used:

```
@BuildMenu(Model)

@helper BuildMenu(IEnumerable<MyMVC.DAL.PageContent> data, int? parentid = null)
{
    ...
}
```

That would mean the `nodes` query result inside the helper will return no results.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the silly mistake i thought i'd made! i have another issue where @node.PageTitle or anything within the foreach statement isn't showing, but i'm sure it's another schoolboy error!